# Не перемещается мышь

Tags: c#

Нужно чтоб камера в игре перемещалась по заданным координатам(некая антиотдача),пишу:

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern long SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hwnd, ref POINT point);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    static private void MoveMouse(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y)
    {
        POINT point = new POINT();

        point.x = Convert.ToInt16(Cursor.Position.X + x);
        point.y = Convert.ToInt16(Cursor.Position.Y + y);

        ClientToScreen(hWnd, ref point);


        SetCursorPos(point.x, point.y);

    }

    static bool isLButtonDown()
    {
        Int16 state = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton);
        return (state & 0x8000) != 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process pro in process)
        {

            if (pro.ProcessName == "Counter-Strike")
                try
                {
                    hWnd = pro.MainWindowHandle;
                    break;
                }
                catch { }
        }


        while (true)
        {
            if (isLButtonDown())
            {
                MoveMouse(hWnd, 0, 1);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(11);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Мышь перемещается при нажатии лкм,но в игре нет,почему?И как сделать чтоб в окне игры работало?
UPD.курсор перемещается,а вот игровая камера нет.А надо чтоб именно она перемещалась.

Comment: try caych там нафига?

Answer (score 1):

На большинстве игр, где "отрицательно" относятся к ботам могут стоять хуки на вызываемые вами API, в итоге вы можете использовать аппаратный эмулятор клавиатуры, который решит ваши проблемы.